# Creating A Backup Table Without Duplicating It

Tags: java, backup

I have a table (let's call it Animal) and I want to create a new backup table (Animal_backup) that has the same attributes of Animal. I want to be sure that if I add an attribute in Animal the same attribute is added in Animal_backup too.
I can't extend Animal in Animal_backup because any entry of Animal_backup will also added in Animal I need to keep them separated.
The only idea I had so far is to create an interface that must be implemented by Animal and Animal_backup but I'm not sure is the best way to handle it.

Also, I have some other tables that extend Animal (Cat,Dog,etc) and I need to backup them too, (Cat_backup,Dog_backup,etc) so I would also have to create other interfaces for them too.

Any ideas?

Comment: You could set private variables for the Animal_Backup, then make a method that uses setters to update the value of these variables everytime a change is made in Animal?

Comment: Are we talking about GUI tables (Swing) or database tables?
If it's GUI tables (backed by collections), would it suffice to just use the same entities (Aninal, Cat, Dog,..) in two collections/tables? If not, would cloned object instances suffice?
Need more information...

Comment: No i can't for the reason below.

They are all Oracle tables. We create them on the Db via Hibernate using:
@Entity.
@Table(name = "Animal")
My bad i forgot to include this information.